# Relative Risk and Odd ratio for N x N x N table

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, odds-ratio, contingency-tables, relative-risk

I am trying to calculate RR for case where I have `N x N x N` table. First N is City (20 cities) second N is Age group (5 groups) and third one is  Industry (4 industries). All values are categorical.  How to reach an answer of the following form: In Stuttgart there is significant number of old people working at Mercedes and significant number of young people work in Crypto in San Francisco.

What would be the proper way to analyse this given the answer i am looking for?

Comment: So you have a total of 400 combinations? How much data do you have in total? How much for each combination?

Comment: I have app. 15000 datapoints not very evenly distributed (eyeballing the numbers) . If i had a clue on how to process this i would have googled for power analysis but at this point i just need an input how to deal with this. Thank you for showing interest for my problem

Comment: Please add new information as an edit to the post and not only as a comment. Comments on this site are ephemeral and often overlooked, and they can be deleted!